# starting C executable in raspbian on startup

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm using raspbian on a raspberry pi and I need to start a program on startup. What is the easiest way to do this? A bash script?

normally I run the following code in terminal:

```
../simple/./simple_run 12345
```

the executable has an input for 12345

Can someone step me through on how to do this?

Comment: Wouldn't this be a better question for the [raspberry pi stack exchange](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Auto-Running a C Program on Raspberry PI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18197252/auto-running-a-c-program-on-raspberry-pi)

Answer (score 2):

Could you call your script at **/etc/rc.local**

If this file doesn't exist, create this:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#

/.../myScript.sh
```

replace */.../myScript.sh* by your script call... use full path.

Only one question... your script will be executed with "root" user... take care!

Comment: what if my script runs infinitely? Would this prevent me from booting?